# Как поправить кнопку в html/css файле?

Tags: html, css

Как сделать так, чтобы рисунок внутри кнопки не выходил за пределы самой кнопки? Если вы вставите этот код, то увидите, что звездочка находится за пределами кнопки. Как сделать так, чтобы звёздочка была всегда внутри кнопки независимо от того, какой размер мы задаем звёздочке и кнопке?

html:

```
<p>
      <button class="button"><p class="symbol">☆</p></button>
</p>
```

css:

```
.button {
  background-color: rgb(168, 194, 233);
  border-radius: 20px;
  outline: none;
  height: 60px;
}
.symbol {
  margin-bottom: 300px;
  font-size: 400%;
}
```

Comment: это же логично что иконка будет за пределами кнопки, высота у вас 60px а отступ снизу у иконки 300px ....не так это делается

Answer (score 2):

Чтобы достичь желаемого результата:

- Не ограничивайте высоту кнопки - пусть её растягивает звёздочка (текст);
- Уберите у параграфов отступы по умолчанию, задав `margin: 0;`
- Установите `line-height` равной размеру шрифта.

```css
.button {
  border-radius: 20px;
  outline: none;
  background-color: rgb(168, 194, 233);
}

.symbol {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 972%;
  line-height: 1em;
}
```

```html
<p>
  <button class="button"><p class="symbol">☆</p></button>
</p>
```

Comment: А можете сделать плавную анимацию увеличения вправо?

Comment: @Silencer: могу, но это уже другой вопрос.